# sbt build is working on local but fails on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, javafx, sbt

I am trying to build project as Jenkins job on server.
I am getting error because of javafx import.
object javafx is not a member of package

```
<root>[0m
13:30:17 [0m[[31merror[0m] [0mimport javafx.scene.control.*;[0m
```

I included the below in build.sbt file

```
unmanagedJars in Compile += Attributed.blank(file(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX is part of Oracle JDK.
Install `Oracle JDK` or add [Automatic JDK](http://www.aurigait.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/pk-41.png) installer to Jenkins.